# Check if Youtube and Vimeo-clips are valid

Tags: php, url

I have been trying for quite a while to check if submitted links are valid film-clips from youtube.com or vimeo.com but I didn't succeed.

Any ideas how to check url's like:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jc0rnCBCX2c&feature=fvhl (valid)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jc0FFCBCX2c&feature=fvhl (not valid)
http://www.youtube.com/v/jc0rnCBCX2c (valid)
http://www.youtube.com/v/ddjcddddX2c (not valid)
http://www.vimeo.com/463l522 (not valid)
http://www.vimeo.com/1483909 (valid)
http://www.vimeo.com/lumiblue (not valid)
http://www.youtube.com/user/dd181921 (not valid)
```

?

I use php.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i see a answer in this site :
www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/JavaScript/Q_23765374.html

and he said :

I would suggest using youtube's API since you are trying to validate if the video exists.
or if you don't want to go into API stuff then you can do simple trick.
check this link:

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/developers_guide_php.html#RetrievingVideoEntry

to check for the existence of a video you will need to extract "v" value and send a request that contains the video id to :

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/videoID

where videoID is the "v" value
for example a video FLE2htv9oxc
will be queried like this
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/FLE2htv9oxc
if it does not exist then you will get a page with "Invalid id"
if it exists, will return an XML feed having various info about the video.
this way you can check that the video exists.

hope this will get you in the right direction.

the same thing with vimeo , try to look in api documentation in there site.
http://www.vimeo.com/api

Comment: Please, PLEASE consider not directly linking to that wretched experts-exchange site in your answer. That site is one of the problems SO has effectively solved. Never mind the `paywall`. I almost edited your answer to de-link it, but .. its not my answer, so I won't. You can cite the source, just take out the "http" part to remove the link.

Comment: Using the api is the correct way to check if a video exists, but be aware that I have experienced YouTube videos not always being available via the api as quickly as they are available to watch on the site. Basically, a link could be valid, while the api says it is not for several minutes.

Answer (score 22):

If you check the response headers from a request to http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/videoId where videoId is the google video Identifier, you should get a 200 if the video exists and a 400 (bad request) if the video doesn't exist.

```
// PHP code

// Check if youtube video item exists by the existance of the the 200 response
$headers = get_headers('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $youtubeId);
if (!strpos($headers[0], '200')) {
    echo "The YouTube video you entered does not exist";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @DavidLawrence: strange, it works for me. I guessed there might be a problem if headers has already been sent, but it works even after something was printed to the screen (i.e. when headers have already been sent). I don't know what was the problem when you tried.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this function to check if the link is a valid youtube link.

```
/**
 * This function will check if 'url' is valid youtube video and return the ID.
 *  If the return value === false then this is **not** a valid youtube url, otherwise   the youtube id is returned.
 *
 * @param <type> $url
 * @return <type>
 */


 private static function get_youtube_id($url) {
        $link = parse_url($url,PHP_URL_QUERY);

    /**split the query string into an array**/
    if($link == null) $arr['v'] = $url;
    else  parse_str($link, $arr);
    /** end split the query string into an array**/
    if(! isset($arr['v'])) return false; //fast fail for links with no v attrib - youtube only

    $checklink = YOUTUBE_CHECK . $arr['v'];

    //** curl the check link ***//
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$checklink);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $return = $arr['v'];
    if(trim($result)=="Invalid id") $return = false; //you tube response

    return $return; //the stream is a valid youtube id.
}
```

Comment: here YOUTUBE_CHECK menas?can you give the details

Comment: YOUTUBE_CHECK = http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/
You can get away with about half that code, and just use the CURL part, and maybe do some preg_match or such to shorten the code. Otherwise this works, and has saved me today.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to catch the 301 header that you tube throws if the video is no longer valid

Answer (score 0):

```
/* 
 * Verify YouTube video status
 */

    $videoID = "o8UCI7r1Aqw";
    $header = get_headers("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/". $videoID);

    switch($headers[0]) {
    case '200':
    // video valid
    break;

    case '403':
    // private video
    break;

    case '404':
    // video not found
    break;

    default:
    // nothing  above
    break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since most of the comments here are a bit old, here's a quick thing I set up that checks if YouTube links are private or not.

The good thing about this approach is that it doesn't require us to set up API Credentials with Google or anything like that. I will assume that you would be able to follow the same approach with Vimeo or any other video provider that doesn't provide accurate status codes on request.

```
axios
    .get(link)
    .then((res) => {
        if (StringUtils.isYouTubeLink(link)) {
            // The "streamingData" substring should be present on
            // all valid video requests. Private or non-existent
            // videos won't have it
            if (!res.data.includes("streamingData")) {
                errorData.reason = "Video unavailable";
                brokenLinks.push(errorData);
            }
        }
    })
```