# ASP.NET MVC get header

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the most efficient way to get headers in ASP.NET MVC

basically, I am trying this approach to validate youtube url:  [Check if Youtube and Vimeo-clips are valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362345/check-if-youtube-and-vimeo-clips-are-valid)

Basically, the link talks about using get_headers in PHP to validate youtube url.

the only problem is I am using C#.NET (ASP.NET MVC) not PHP.

How should I efficiently get header?

Comment: you're title and the content of the question don't really jive.  explain what you want to have happen.

Comment: actually the link talks about getting header in php to validate youtube url. I want to do the same in ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to do this server-side and would use an [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx).  The accepted answer on [Why Does my HttpWebRequest Return 400 Bad request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702079/c-simple-httpwebrequest-question) should get you started.  Essentially, what you'll want to do is verify that the request succeeds and check the relevant headers.  If you only want the headers, set the method to **HEAD** instead of **GET**.

Comment: that worked except how do I catch 400?? Right now, my code works fine if it's a valid url, otherwise it throws an WebException. How do I capture 400?

Comment: @progtick - use a try/catch for the `WebException` and examine the `Status` property in the catch block if you need to differentiate between errors.  I believe that a 400 error would show up as a `ProtocolError`.  You might also have to look at the `Message` if greater granularity is needed.