# Checking embedded youtube video in pdf and redirect if they are changed or broken

Tags: php, pdf, video, redirect, youtube

Here is the problem: We have some pdf files with youtube videos embedded in them. Obviously if the videos are deleted/changed, we want to know about it. The plan is that we hold some urls on our own server which we embed into the pdfs. Each of these urls are linked to a youtube video. So if for example the youtube video is deleted we don't have to modify the pdf, but change the youtube video url linked to the url in the pdf. In short we would embed links in the pdf to our own server and these links would redirect to youtube.

I think with cron and md5_file the checking of the video changes can be done, though there is one concern. If i do md5_file on a youtube video page, then i believe it acts on the whole page and will show a change has happened even when only a comment was added to the video. So i guess i would need the direct link to the video and md5_file that.
Another part is that i wonder if the pdf can show the youtube video correctly with this redirect mechanism.

If anyone has some idea or experience with similar stuff, please share your knowledge.
Thank You
Alex

Comment: Do the videos show correctly in the PDF if you link directly to the YouTube site? I would have expected that would need a direct link to the video file as well.

Comment: Good question and (unfortunately) you are absolutely right. I misunderstood the email of the guy who asked me to solve this problem(he was talking about embedded videos like it's already done). After wasting an hour to embed a youtube video i asked them to send a test.pdf and i wasn't surprised anymore that it didn't contain any video. So it's looks like only a plan at the moment. The first step is to solve this. I found a page: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/866214#3745965 . Maybe this is doable this way, but still then all the security issues with the upcoming messages, don't really like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the YouTube-API [Retrieving Video Entry](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html#Retrieving_Video_Entry), e.g. using Zend Framework's [Zend_GData_Youtube](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.youtube.html).

**edit** (for clarification): I haven't used the YouTube-API myself, but I assume when a video is deleted an error, rather than the usual output, is returned on which you can react.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested solving the whole problem, here is what i did.

1. Created a flash video player with the youtube api which communicates with server side php.
2. The server side returns videoIds from database depending what info it gets from the flash.
3. Another php server side script updates the database if some video is broken(using cron). In this script the proper way would be to use the API(see accepted answer), but it's possible to do it without it, see the following link.
   [Check if Youtube and Vimeo-clips are valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362345/check-if-youtube-and-vimeo-clips-are-valid)