# Check if a YouTube video has been removed using PHP?

Tags: php, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if Youtube and Vimeo-clips are valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362345/check-if-youtube-and-vimeo-clips-are-valid)

I have a website which links to a lot of YouTube videos but a lot of the time these videos are removed by either the user or YouTube. This means my site has a lot of dead videos on it and there are so many it would be a nightmare to check them all manually.

So I am looking for a way to check if the YouTube video is still valid using PHP. I have seen a lot of threads with people asking the same question but I can't get any of the posted solutions to work.

Comment: Please provide some examples of the links (or what you use to identify) of videos that have been removed and some which are still working.

Answer (score 8):

Use youtube V3 API to check if the video is accessible or not. For further info refer to the following doc

> https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

Basically, make a GET request using your API key

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id&id={VIDEO_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

You will receive a sample response like:

> ```
> {
>  "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
>  "etag": "\"sZ5p5Mo8dPpfIzLYQBF8QIQJym0/N6KWrfNRyfPOarHfhvNS7j4jfxM\"",
>  "pageInfo": {
>   "totalResults": 0,
>   "resultsPerPage": 0
>  },
>  "items": []
> }*
> ```

If you get an empty array in `items` of response, the video is not accessible.

---

The following says about V2 of the API, which is now deprecated.
(https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_entries).

> Note: The YouTube Data API (v2) has been officially deprecated as of March 4, 2014. Please refer to our deprecation policy for more information. Please use the YouTube Data API (v3) for new integrations and migrate applications still using the v2 API to the v3 API as well.

Send request to this URL, to verify the existence of a video

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/<videoid>
```

Here is an usage of it.

```
$headers = get_headers('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $videoId);
if (!strpos($headers[0], '200')) {
    echo "The YouTube video you entered does not exist";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter, Can't you leave some comment, while downvoting?

Comment: if I do this request on every pageview (I mean, everytime a user tries to access the web) is there a chance youtube api will block me?

Comment: Does that still work? I am getting "Video No Longer Available" for even valid youtube video ids

Comment: @Sudar, Yeah the method in this answer is deprecated. I have updated with a guide to use new API version.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply check the return value of `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/$id`

You get back for example

- Private video
- Invalid id
- Video not found

So the simplest check would be:

```
if (file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'.$videoId) == 'Video not found') {
  echo 'Video deleted';
}
```

Comment: Mr Dan Lee, Please mind your language. Its about a clean post without duplicate answers. And considering your answer which is pretty bad quality anyway.

Answer (score 2):

With using youtube api, you can check yt:state attribute:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube%5Fdata%5Fapi%5Ftag%5Fyt%3Astate

Comment: API v2 is deprecated. Please see this comment for v3: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30197080/1252245

Answer (score 0):

Youtube returns a HTTP status code 404 is the video isn't there.
[See this made up url](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IytNBmyWA1c), for example.

The specific error message differs, but the important thing is a non 200 code is returned.

So in PHP use Curl to fetch the url, then check what status code is returned.
You can get the status code from Curl with something like this:

```
$http_status = curl_getinfo( $handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
```

You could store a last_checked timestamp with each url in a database, then have a cronjob running every N mins to check a small number of urls, and update the timestamps when you're done. Make sure to store the status code in the database as well.

Then you can deal with non 200 status codes however you like in your code, when showing the url.