# How to use YouTube API to check if a video is restricted?

Tags: youtube-data-api

When embedding this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/embed/dYQ2IyMuPes) for example, we get `This video contains content from... who has blocked it from display on the website` error message.

How can I use the API to find if a video is blocked or not?

The nearest parameters I found are `status` and `contentDetails`:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=status&id=dYQ2IyMuPes&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Which returns no indication about the restriction:

```
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT2M",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "false",
    "licensedContent": true,
    "projection": "rectangular"
   },
   "status": {
    "uploadStatus": "processed",
    "privacyStatus": "public",
    "license": "youtube",
    "embeddable": true,
    "publicStatsViewable": false
   }
```

Comment: same post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190620/how-do-i-check-if-a-youtube-video-is-blocked-restricted-deleted

Comment: Similar question, however the answer doesn't solve my issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Check if it is restricted in the region `contentDetails.regionRestriction` or age-restricted content `contentDetails.contentRating` or content claimed by partner `contentDetails.licensedContent`? I am just speculating here too.

Edit: You can use this to check if it is embeddable too `status.embeddable`.

Comment: Both status and contentDetails does not show any indication of the restriction. I've updated the question to make it more clear, thanks.

Comment: You can access the video directly from browser right?

Comment: The video works fine for me in browser (youtube.com). And your status response shows embeddable=true. I guess I cant figure it out, sorry! Good luck!

Comment: Have you clicked on the link in the question and played the video?

Comment: Yea, it is playing fine on both my android chrome browser and in my android youtube app

Comment: I see your error message when trying to view the sample embedded video from Japan. Geo-locked?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have the "part" set correctly. It's a required field and you probably have "snippet there" and you need "contentDetails". (or "snippet,contentDetails" for both)

Example:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=OoKpYXTmYak&key={YOUR_API_KEY}


{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/Xn7P-qyclepPOIFp9Bn69FdtR-4\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/_vu8XkjotVqxtJKQ2peTcRK8TYE\"",
   "id": "OoKpYXTmYak",
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT1M41S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "false",
    "licensedContent": true,
    "regionRestriction": {
     "allowed": [
      "ES",
      "US"
     ]
    },
    "projection": "rectangular"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

This is allowed in the US and Spain only