# Use Youtube API V3 check the video copyright whether is claimed by partner,but licensedContent is not working

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I uploaded two videos to Youtube, one of copyright  which was claimed and the other one not. I want to found the video claiming copyright through Youtube API V3.

Before that, I have read the similar issues. It is said that I can judge **licensedContent** field of the video.

But all the two videos return **contentDetails.licensedContent**  was **false**

```
"items":[{"contentDetails":{"caption":"false","definition":"hd","dimension":"2d","duration":"PT4M30S","hasCustomThumbnail":false
```

---

I would like to ask what is the reason, or there are other ways to solve this question.

thanks.

Comment: Based from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761944/how-to-use-youtube-api-to-check-if-a-video-is-restricted), `licensedContent` is working. You could check the license status of the video and the video's restricted region. Those should be related to your issue.